# kubectl apply -f <spec.yaml> equivalent in fabric8 java api

Tags: kubernetes, fabric8

I was trying to use io.fabric8 api to create a few resources in kubernetes using a pod-spec.yaml.

```
Config config = new ConfigBuilder()
                  .withNamespace("ag")
                  .withMasterUrl(K8_URL)
                  .build();
try (final KubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient(config)) {

            LOGGER.info("Master: " + client.getMasterUrl());

            LOGGER.info("Loading File : " + args[0]);
            Pod pod = client.pods().load(new FileInputStream(args[0])).get();
            LOGGER.info("Pod created with name : " + pod.toString());

} catch (Exception e) {

            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);

}
```

The above code works if the resource type is of POD. Similarly for other resource type it is working fine.
But if the yaml has multiple resource type like POD and service in the same file, how to use fabric8 Api ?

I was trying to use `client.load(new FileInputStream(args[0])).createOrReplace();` but it is crashing with the below exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3042)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.URLUtils.join(URLUtils.java:48)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.getMandatory(BaseOperation.java:208)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.get(BaseOperation.java:177)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.handlers.PodHandler.reload(PodHandler.java:53)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.handlers.PodHandler.reload(PodHandler.java:32)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.NamespaceVisitFromServerGetWatchDeleteRecreateWaitApplicableListImpl.createOrReplace(NamespaceVisitFromServerGetWatchDeleteRecreateWaitApplicableListImpl.java:202)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.NamespaceVisitFromServerGetWatchDeleteRecreateWaitApplicableListImpl.createOrReplace(NamespaceVisitFromServerGetWatchDeleteRecreateWaitApplicableListImpl.java:62)
    at com.nokia.k8s.InterpreterLanuch.main(InterpreterLanuch.java:66)
```

Yaml file used

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  generateName: zep-ag-pod
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/psp: restricted
    spark-app-name: Zeppelin-spark-shared-process
  namespace: ag
  labels:
    app: zeppelin
    int-app-selector: shell-123

spec:
  containers:
    - name: ag-csf-zep
      image: bcmt-registry:5000/zep-spark2.2:9
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      command: ["/bin/bash"]
      args: ["-c","echo Hi && sleep 60 && echo Done"]
      securityContext:
        allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
        capabilities:
          drop:
          - ALL
        runAsNonRoot: true
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 2000
    runAsUser: 1510
  serviceAccount: csfzeppelin
  serviceAccountName: csfzeppelin
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zeppelin-service
  namespace: ag
  labels:
    app: zeppelin
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: zeppelin-service
    port: 30099
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: zeppelin
```

Comment: Using the following versions: 
io.fabric8 - 4.1.0
kubernetes - 1.11.2

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to specify resource type whenever loading a file with multiple documents. You simply need to do:

```
  // Load Yaml into Kubernetes resources
  List<HasMetadata> result = client.load(new FileInputStream(args[0])).get();
  // Apply Kubernetes Resources
  client.resourceList(result).inNamespace(namespace).createOrReplace()
```

Comment: If i do a get. I have to iterate the List and check if the resource is instance of pod or is instance of service. Is there any way to apply the entire yaml which creates all resources in it ?

Comment: No, you don't need to do that. You can apply that list onto cluster via `client.resourceList(result).inNamespace(namespace).createOrReplace()`

Comment: Tried this but getting the above Exception: 
`Config config = new ConfigBuilder().withNamespace("ag").withMasterUrl(K8_URL).build(); 

KubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient(config)); java.util.List<HasMetadata> resources = client.load(new FileInputStream(args[0])).get(); 

client.resourceList(resources)..inNamespace("ag").createOrReplace();`

Comment: Could you please share your resource yaml if possible? I tested this on minikube and it seemed to work

Comment: I have updated the yaml file in the question. Can you please take a look @RohanKumar

Comment: Your yaml seems to be invalid. You're not providing `name` field in Pod metadata

Comment: I thought generateName will generate a random name by appending zep-ag-pod-<randomNumber> . If i use kubectl apply -f <yaml> I am seeing both my pod and service coming up

Comment: I think this generateName feature is not supported in client right now. Could you please file an issue at the repo and use `name` field in the meantime?

Comment: Oh okay, will try with `name`. If its working will update and raise a JIRA.

Comment: We use GitHub for issue tracking ;-) . Although I like JIRA a lot

Comment: Oh okay.. Sure will check with `name` and if working will raise an issue. Thanks for the help

Comment: Thanks for the help with "name" its working. I had 1 more doubt if i add a "role" or "roleBinding" resource the code throws a NullPointerException. I found out that i can use `client.rbac().kubernetesRoles().create(role);`. But is there a way to apply role and roleBinding through `client.resourceList(resources).createOrReplace();` ?

Comment: I think this is bug in client. Could you please file an issue there so that it doesn't get lost?

Comment: Yes. I will report it. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help.
Reported this issue. https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/issues/1299

Comment: Thanks, will try getting this issue fixed before next release :-)