# What are the Java API options for deploying docker image on Kubernetes?

Tags: java, api, kubernetes

I am looking for suggestions on Java API for Kubernetes that I can deploy docker image on kubernetes. My end goal is to be able to deploy docker image on kubernetes programmatically using Java. My current way to deploy the docker image is using the cmd `kubectl create -f xxx.yaml`.

I have been googling, but I am unable to find much information for the Java API for this matter. It doesn't see that kubernetes client can handle this either. Appreciated with all the help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

One tool in this space is the fabric8 Java client. You can use it to programmatically create and apply resources - https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/kubernetes-examples/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/examples/FullExample.java

Or to apply yaml from a file [kubectl apply -f <spec.yaml> equivalent in fabric8 java api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53501540/kubectl-apply-f-spec-yaml-equivalent-in-fabric8-java-api)

Comment: Thanks. I read about fabric8, but one part I am not quite sure is:  if I use fabric8 api, do i need to install anything on the kubernetes side?

Comment: No, you don't have to install anything on cluster to use the kubernetes client

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [Java Kubernetes Client SDK](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/examples/YamlExample.java). May be this can help. Look at that entire repo for examples.